# JSP page import does not work on JBoss

Tags: jsp, jboss

I am using the following in one of my jsp's. In eclipse it shows the error:

> The import com.nucleus.core.loanproduct.ContractType cannot be
>   resolved

But on starting jetty up, the class is resolved and any usages of the var `contractTypeLoan` do not give any error. But the same project when deployed on a 
JBoss server, gives the said error.

```
<%@ page import="com.nucleus.core.loanproduct.ContractType"%>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // static final String LOAN = "Loan"; in Contract Type
 var contractTypeLoan = "<%=ContractType.LOAN%>";
  </script>
 ..............
 ..............
 function applyContractTypeChanges(){
    contractTypeSelected = $("#contractType option:selected").text();
     if(contractTypeSelected == contractTypeLoan){
         // Check always fails.
     }
```

Is this some issue with JBoss?